# Python: Equation symbolic solution

Tags: python, symbolic-math

I was wondering if there was any way I could get the symbolic solution for a variable in an equation using python, as I've been looking around but didn't find exactly what I wanted. What I intend to do is, for example, given:

`eq =  x + y + 5`

I'd like to get:

`x = - 5 - y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x, y')
expr = x + y + 5
solve(expr, x)
>>>Out: [-5-y]
```

Comment: That was it! I checked solve(), but didn't saw any case like this and I couldn't try it right now, so thank you!